# How do large landowners affect a state?

Tags: land

I read the Unbound Savanna chapter in *[Progress and Poverty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_and_Poverty)*, and I saw a video summary of [Marc Bloch's *Feudal Societies*](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/F/bo3641119.html). Truly, I am a worldly man.

Anyway do economists and sociologists say if majority landowners e.g., churches, kings, the middle class, affect the attitudes of the time?

Comment: This is a fascinating question.   I want to have the time to do some research. May vary by state an era.  One theory of the difference between French and English history is the difference in large landowners (England is originally WIlliam's personal possession; France has very powerful nobles and a less powerful king).  IIRC Pitt manipulated the "country gentlemen" to great advantage.  Virginia's disproportionate role in the US Federal period is in part due to the presence of large landowners.

Comment: OTOH, the Baron's war/Magna Carta could not happen without disproportionate large landholders. It would be interesting to explore the distribution of land ownership in Spanish, Italian and German state formation, or to look at Austria-Hungary or Russia

Comment: Since there question is not restricted in time. [UnmitigatedPedantry](https://acoup.blog/2023/03/10/collections-how-to-polis-101-part-i-component-parts/)'s comments on the hoi ologoi in the polis are relevant. Although totalmongot is correct, that was not a "state"

Comment: @MCW: Yet, contrast Versailles and Louis XIV as the archetypical *Absolute Monarch* even as the English Civil War is going on, followed by the Glorious Revolution.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the answer depends deeply on multiple factors:

- Place
- Time
- What do you call "attitude of the time", and what do you call "state"?
- Do you want to know if one or another majority landowner affect, or if having a majority landowner vs. not having affect?

But, if I assume that "attitude" is about "how lands are used", and that you want to know if "having a majority landowner vs. not having affect this use", then an answer could be given.

From Antiquity to 19th century, having a majority of big landowners instead of "poor workers of their own land" did not affect massively farming techniques, because there were few "buying tickets". Most cultures were made either in communities or under the rule of land owner. The only examples were when specific laws expelled poor workers from the lands, such as under the Clearances in Scotland.

Comment: So would a better question be, "How did the Highland Clearances affect religion/inequality/politics etc.?

Comment: @EthanMiller If you want to know about this famous example of "land owners affected", yes. But overall your question needs to be clarified